# Como pegar a data correta usando momentjs

Tags: javascript, timestamp, timezone, momentjs

Fala pessoal.

Eu estou tendo alguns problema tentando utilizar a library momentjs para trabalhar com datas.

Meu problema está descrito abaixo.

```
****--------- Datetime ----------****

Timestamp recebido do banco de dados -> 2016-07-12 17:21:40 <- ESTA É A DATA 'UTC' QUE ESTA RETORNANDO DO BANCO COMO STRING

moment.tz(datetime, moment.tz.guess()); //datetime value is '2016-07-12 17:21:40' and moment.tz.guess() is returning "America/Sao_Paulo"

// inspect the moment object returned
q{ _isAMomentObject:true, _i:"2016-07-12 17:21:40", _f:"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", _isUTC:true, _pf:Object…} 
_a: Array[7]
_d:Tue Jul 12 2016 14:21:40GMT-0300 (BRT) <- ESTA É A DATA CORRETA QUE EU QUERO
_f:"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
_i:"2016-07-12 17:21:40"
_isAMomentObject:true
_isUTC:true
_isValid:true
_locale:B
_offset:-180
_pf:Object
_z:h
__proto__:Object

// moment object formatted .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
2016-07-12 17:21:40 <- ESSA É A DATA QUE ESTA RETORNANDO, E ESTA ERRADA

****-------------------****
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o por que disso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa criar o objeto moment com uma data UTC e não local. Veja:

```
var dataUtc = moment.utc("2016-07-12 17:21:40");
moment.tz(dataUtc, moment.tz.guess()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

No seu caso, ficaria algo assim:

```
moment.tz(moment.utc(datetime), moment.tz.guess());
```

Comment: valeu. Funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta assim fera:

```
moment(new Date(dataretornadadobanco)).format('padrao')

Lista de padrões: 
moment.locale('pt-br');         // :|
moment().format('LT');   // 11:39 AM
moment().format('LTS');  // 11:39:41 AM
moment().format('L');    // 07/13/2016
moment().format('l');    // 7/13/2016
moment().format('LL');   // July 13, 2016
moment().format('ll');   // Jul 13, 2016
moment().format('LLL');  // July 13, 2016 11:39 AM
moment().format('lll');  // Jul 13, 2016 11:39 AM
moment().format('LLLL'); // Wednesday, July 13, 2016 11:39 AM
moment().format('llll');  // Wed, Jul 13, 2016 11:40 AM
```

Se quiser pegar só a data tira o format e pega o _d...

Comment: Não é uma boa prática pegar diretamente o valor da variável **_d** pois essa é uma variável de uso interno da library. Alias eu acredito que seja um bug elas estar exposta assim. Ela deveria ter dentro de um closure.